# In how many ways can you pull 4 balls out of 9 ? (every ball is different)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Simple question but i get confused..

> In how many **ways** can you pull 4 balls out of 9 ? (every ball is different)

- Is this permutation or combination and why ?

Got confused because I don't understand whether "how many ways" mean that the arrangement is important or not ..

Comment: What is the exact wording of the question?  Combinations are used when you are selecting a subset.  Permutations are used when you are arranging a subset.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that.. Exactly what is  confusing me is the wording.. That is the exact wording :#

Comment: The reason I questioned the wording is that it is not grammatically correct.  The word can should precede the word you.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks, it is translated and the emphasized word was "ways"..

Comment: The problem is not phrased properly.

Comment: The emphasis on the word ways makes me lean toward the interpretation that the order in which the balls are pulled matters, which would make this a permutations question.  That said, I understand your confusion about the author's intent.

Answer (score 0):

Permutation is when you order a set, combination is, when you select elements from the set.

The permutations of the set $\{1,2,3\}$ are:
$\{1,2,3\}\{1,3,2\}\{2,1,3\}\{2,3,1\}\{3,1,2\}\{3,2,1\}$

if you say, "some combination of these numbers opens the gate", you mean, that some of elements from the set is the code, the others are not

So in your example, it's a combination,

Answer (score 0):

So your question is whether to solve the problem by using combination or "k-permutations of n objects" (earlier called variation). If the question is stated *exactly* how you did it, it is **k-permutations of n objects**, because the emphasis is on the **way** of pulling balls out, not the result. But it might be just my subjective understanding of the question and knowing further context would help a lot. Otherwise the problem is not very well stated.

It might help to show us the original source of this problem.

---

Now imagine a little example, which will hopefully show you my thinking process:

There is a lottery, in which above rules apply. You can guess just the **balls** or you can guess the **balls** and the **order** in which they are pulled out. If you need to count probability of a right guess, you will have to use k-permutations of n objects for total number of possibilities in both cases anyway. The only difference will be in the number of permutations that are successful for you.

Why? Because even thought the result is sometimes the same (so it looks like we can use combinations), the ways are different and you have to count with everything that happens.